# instantiate an abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Icollection` like this:

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ICollection
{
public:
    virtual void add(T) = 0;
    virtual T get(int) = 0;
    virtual int count() = 0;
};
```

and a derived class `ArdalanCollection` like this:

```
#include "iCollection.h"
#include <map>
template <typename T>
class ArdalanCollection :public ICollection<T>
{
public:
    ArdalanCollection(){
        index = 0;
    };
    virtual void add(T obj){
        encapsolateImplementation.insert(make_pair(index++, obj));
    };
    virtual T get(int index){
        return encapsolateImplementation[index];
    };

    virtual int count(){
        return index;
    }
private:
    int index;
    map < int, T > encapsolateImplementation;
};
```

now I have another abstract class named `abs_class` like this:

```
class abs_class
{
public:
    abs_class(){};
    virtual int getT(int) = 0;
protected:
    int Kg;
};
```

what I want to do is constructing an object of `Icollection` of type `abs_class`, in other words I want to do this:

```
ICollection<abs_class> *eles = new ArdalanCollection <abs_class>();
```

but I reasonably got this error:

> error C2259: 'abs_class' : cannot instantiate abstract class

is there any way to turn around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying `abs_class` as the template type `T`, but `T` needs to be constructible, since `add` takes a `T` by value and `get` returns a `T` by value.

Since `abs_class` is pure virtual it can't be instantiated. You could use `abs_class*` instead, or provide an inherited class with the `getT` member defined.

Comment: yeah actually I already did your second remedy but somehow I needed to use your first one! thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate abstract class. That means you can't use:-

```
ICollection<abs_class> *eles;
```

However you can do this:-

```
ICollection<abs_class*> *eles;
```